# Reshape a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have in my Code the following Matrix:

```
M=[[1, 1,  0],
  [2, 1,  0],
  [3, 1,  0],
  [4, 1,  3],
  [5, 1,  0],
  [6, 1,  4],
  [7, 1,  4],
  [8, 1,  5],
  [1, 2,  0],
  [2, 2,  2],
  [3, 2,  7],
  [4, 2,  3],
  [5, 2,  0],
  [6, 2,  3],
  [7, 2,  0],
  [8, 2,  5],
  [1, 3,  1],
  [2, 3,  1],
  [3, 3,  0],
  [4, 3,  3],
  [5, 3,  6],
  [6, 3,  5],
  [7, 3,  4],
  [8, 3,  0]]
```

And I would like to reshape it into the following one

```
new_M=[[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4, 5],
      [0, 2, 7, 3, 0, 3, 0, 5],
      [1, 1, 0, 3, 6, 5, 4, 0]]
```

I've tried with the following Code:

```
new_M=[]
l=0
for j in range(3):
    for k in range(8):
        new_M[j][k]=M[l][2]
        l=l+1
```

But I get the following error: IndexError: list index out of range

I'd appreciate a way to fix this Code or a better Code to perform the same Task. 
PD: I'd also appreciate a detailed Explanation fo the Code because I'm Kind of new using Python.

Thank you so much in Advance.

Comment: Do you need to use the two first cols to reshape? otherwise `M[:,-1].reshape(3,int(len(M)/3))`

Comment: Also you do know that you have an index problem, right?

Comment: Seems like a sparse to dense array problem, why don't use use scipy sparse matrices?

Comment: Agreed @MatthieuBrucher, simplest way when it comes to constructing matrices from data and col/row indices

Comment: Indeed, that's your answer :)

Comment: Does your `M` specify all points, in order, without duplicates?  That determines whether a simple reshape is enough, or if a more general mapping is needed.  Your code is ok if `new_M` is initialled correctly, e.g. `np.zeros((3,8),int)` (and adjusting for 0 based indexing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numpy` can do you many wonderful jobs:

```
import numpy as np

np.array(M)[:, 2].reshape(3,8)
array([[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4, 5],
      [0, 2, 7, 3, 0, 3, 0, 5],
      [1, 1, 0, 3, 6, 5, 4, 0]])
```

In case the first two columns are actually the 2d-indices:

```
my_arr = np.array(M)
new_arr = np.zeros((3,8))
np.add.at(new_arr, (my_arr[:,1]-1, my_arr[:,0]-1), my_arr[:,2])
print(new_arr)
[[0. 0. 0. 3. 0. 4. 4. 5.]
 [0. 2. 7. 3. 0. 3. 0. 5.]
 [1. 1. 0. 3. 6. 5. 4. 0.]]
```

Comment: I suppose the first two columns should be used in case there are gaps, or not ordered.

Answer (score 1):

One option if you want to use the two first columns to construct the `ndarray` is to use [`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html).

In this case you can build the sparse row matrix by specifying:

> csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), [shape=(M, N)]):
>
> where data, row_ind and col_ind satisfy the relationship a[row_ind[k], col_ind[k]] = data[k].

---

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
x = np.array(M)

sp = csr_matrix((x[:,-1], (x[:,1]-1, x[:,0]-1)))
sp.todense()

matrix([[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4, 5],
        [0, 2, 7, 3, 0, 3, 0, 5],
        [1, 1, 0, 3, 6, 5, 4, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Note:  The indices of both the rows and columns should start at `0`, that's why I'm substracting `1`